# Why my focus is not working properly it only works for active?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a css and when im writing:

```
.rate:not(:checked) > label:active,
.rate:not(:checked) > label:active ~ label {
    color: red;
}
```

it works fine but for this code its not working:

```
.rate:not(:checked) > label:focus,
    .rate:not(:checked) > label:focus ~ label {
        color: black;
    }
```

HTML CODE:

```
 <div class="rate p-0">
     <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rate" value="5" />
     <label for="star5" title="text">5 stars</label>
     <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rate" value="4" />
     <label for="star4" title="text">4 stars</label>
     <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rate" value="3" />
     <label for="star3" title="text">3 stars</label>
     <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rate" value="2" />
     <label for="star2" title="text">2 stars</label>
     <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rate" value="1" />
     <label for="star1" title="text">1 star</label>
 </div>
```

Comment: `.rate` is a `<div>`. It can never be `:checked`. See [change label color radio when checked](/q/46901698/4642212).

Comment: @SebastianSimon how can i make it work ?

Comment: How about `.rate input:not(checked)...`?

Comment: @kiner_shah thanks for answering, its not working.

Comment: BTW, what kind of effect do you expect?

Comment: @kiner_shah It just need to be focused on click  and the color has to be green

Comment: @kiner_shah It would have to be `.rate input:not(:checked)`.

Comment: @connexo, Ohh yes, my bad.

Comment: @connexo not working :)

Comment: Labels don't have focus, the input element has.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```css
input[type="radio"]:focus+label {
  color: red;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="rate p-0">
  <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rate" value="5" />
  <label for="star5" title="text">5 stars</label>
  <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rate" value="4" />
  <label for="star4" title="text">4 stars</label>
  <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rate" value="3" />
  <label for="star3" title="text">3 stars</label>
  <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rate" value="2" />
  <label for="star2" title="text">2 stars</label>
  <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rate" value="1" />
  <label for="star1" title="text">1 star</label>
</div>
```